# need help programming buttons in applescript

Tags: button, applescript

I'm trying to add some buttons at the end of a small program that will end uo being pretty extensive when all is said and done. once the program is run I'm want 3 buttons {"Show formula", "return to list", "exit"}

I have no idea what I'm doing lol, I'm basically constantly googling while I'm writing this and I think I need help

I had some code after the buttons option but it kept giving me "end" errors. I deleted the code and I forget that I had to show yall

[here's my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lYNVz.png)

```
set x to item 1 of (choose from list {"Divers consumption at depth", "Free gas volume", "Price list"})
if x is "Divers consumption at depth" then
    display dialog "what is divers breathing volume (default 1.4 l/min?" default answer "1.4"
    set varDvol to text returned of result
    display dialog "What is divers absolute depth pressure" default answer ""
    set varPbar to text returned of result
    set answer to varDvol * varPbar
    display dialog "Diver consumption is " & answer as text buttons {"See formula", "Return to list", "Exit"}
```

I would like the buttons to just what they say. the show formula button would show "Consumption = volume * pressure", return to list would return to the original list if another function needs to be preformed, and exit would exit the application

Comment: Your code doesn't compile without an `end if` to match the `if`.

Comment: So what's the question? You are saying `display dialog "Diver consumption is " & answer as text buttons {"See formula", "Return to list", "Exit"}`. Now what? Are you asking us just _write_ the code that comes after that? That's not going to happen...

Comment: yea that's not the whole code, I managed to fine one online throughout my searching and copied and pasted to get the whole code and I just changed areas where necessary. so that's not the whole thing. AND no I'm not asking you to write the code, I'm just asking for a hand. like I said, I want it to display the answer (display dialog "diver consumption is ...." then below that have option buttons to either see the formula used to get the result, or return to the main list, or exit the app.

Comment: But you're already doing that. Your last `display dialog` puts up exactly that - the text "diver consumption is..." with those three buttons. So what's the problem?

Comment: I can't find how to make the buttons perform the action, go to another window for the formula, return to the original list, or exit the program

Comment: Well you have to proceed in the following code to look at what button was clicked and do whatever you want to do based on that.

Answer (score 0):

You are looking for a structure like this:

```
display dialog "Diver consumption is " & answer as text buttons {"See formula", "Return to list", "Exit"}
set response to button returned of result
if response = "See formula" then
    #do one thing
else if response = "Return to list" then
    #do a different thing
else if response = "Exit" then
    #do a third thing
end if
```